# Can I select only the id and @ManyToMany columns in springboot-data-jpa?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In a entity, I want to query only the ID and the ManyToMany columns.

```
public class Article {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(length = 64)
  @Size(max = 64)
  @NotEmpty
  private String title;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @ToString.Exclude
  @NotEmpty
  @JoinTable(
      name = "article_tag",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "articleId"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagId"))
  private Set<Tag> tags;
  //...other fields
}
```

I'm trying with this jpql

```
  @Query("SELECT a.tags,a.id FROM Article a WHERE a.id in :ids")
  List<Article> findIdAndTags(List<Long> ids);
```

But I got a sql syntax error. Because the sql that hibernate generated contains '.' as a colum_name

```
 select
        . as col_0_0_,
        article0_.id as col_1_0_,
        tag2_.id as id1_45_,
        tag2_.circleId as circleid6_45_,
        tag2_.createdTime as createdt2_45_,
        tag2_.essence as essence3_45_,
        tag2_.modifiedTime as modified4_45_,
        tag2_.name as name5_45_ 
    from
        article article0_ 
    inner join
        article_tag tags1_ 
            on article0_.id=tags1_.articleId 
    inner join
        tag tag2_ 
            on tags1_.tagId=tag2_.id 
    where
        article0_.id in (
            ? , ? , ?
        )
```

I expect a correct sql such as

```
select
        article0_.id as col_1_0_,
        tag2_.id as id1_45_,
        tag2_.circleId as circleid6_45_,
        tag2_.createdTime as createdt2_45_,
        tag2_.essence as essence3_45_,
        tag2_.modifiedTime as modified4_45_,
        tag2_.name as name5_45_ 
    from
        article article0_ 
    inner join
        article_tag tags1_ 
            on article0_.id=tags1_.articleId 
    inner join
        tag tag2_ 
            on tags1_.tagId=tag2_.id 
    where
        article0_.id in (
            ? , ? , ?
        )
```

And I can get a Article entity with only the id and tags field, others are null.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a plural attribute directly, but have to join it. Use the following query instead:

```
@Query("SELECT t,a.id FROM Article a JOIN a.tags t WHERE a.id in :ids")
List<Article> findIdAndTags(List<Long> ids);
```

Comment: Thank you. There is no problem with sql generation and execution now. But now i get a `Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query io.transwarp.community.bean.article.Article]` Do  i have to use `new Article(id,tags)...`, or there is another way to make jpa auto convert?

Comment: You have to use the JPQL constructor syntax i.e. `select new my.company.MyDTO(t, a.id) ...`